# What is different from getString with String in java?

Tags: java, json

I have some json like `[{"person":"123abc"}]` in variable `JSON_STRING` i try parse json to string like this

```
    JSONObject person = (new JSONObject(JSON_STRING));
    String name = person.getString("person");
    String test= "123abc";
    if(name == test){
       System.out.print("Success");
    }else{
       System.out.print("Fail");
    }
```

I make some simple logic with if else but i have some problem variable `name` and `test`not same because result `Fail`. I don't know why content variable `name` and `test` considered not same. Please help if anyone have some solution.

Thanks

Comment: do you know the difference between "==" and .equals() in java ?

Comment: Please compare strings with `equals`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
if(name == test){
```

You compare references not values. Use :

```
if(name.equals(test)){
```

Comment: actually, he does compare the string(s). I think you mean: "You compare references, not values"

Comment: Yes, I changed it

Comment: thanks for simple explanation and it work

Answer (score 1):

`if(name == test){` should be `if(name.equals(test)){`

`==`is used to compare references, and `equals` is using to compare values